# How to use order by and rownum without subselect?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, rownum

I need to build a query with a order by and rownum but without use a sublect. 
It is needed to get the first row of the query ordered.

In other words, I want the result of

```
select * from (
SELECT CAMP1,ORDERCAMP
FROM TABLENAME
ORDER BY ORDERCAMP) where rownum=1;
```

but **whithout use a subselect**. Is it possible?

I have a Oracle 11. You could say this is my whole query:

```
SELECT T1.CAMP_ID,
  T2.CAMP
  (SELECT OT.CAMP
  FROM OTHERTABLE OT
  WHERE OT.FK_TO_TABLE1=T1.CAMP_ID
  ORDER BY OT.ORDERCAMP
  )
FROM TABLE1 T1,
  TABLE2 T2
WHERE T1.FK_TO_T2=T2.PK;
```

The subquery returns more than one row, and I cant use another subquery like

```
SELECT T1.CAMP_ID,
  T2.CAMP
  (SELECT *
  FROM
    (SELECT OT.CAMP
    FROM OTHERTABLE OT
    WHERE OT.FK_TO_TABLE1=T1.CAMP_ID
    ORDER BY OT.ORDERCAMP
    )
  WHERE ROWNUM=1
  )
FROM TABLE1 T1,
  TABLE2 T2
WHERE T1.FK_TO_T2=T2.PK;
SELECT CAMP1,ORDERCAMP FROM TABLE2 ORDER BY ORDERCAMP
```

Because the `T1.CAMP_ID` is an invalid identifier in the third level subquery.

I hope I have explained myself enough.

Comment: Which version are you using? And why don't you want to use a subquery; is this an exercise or a limitation of a tool you're using? Would a CTE count as a subquery for your purposes?

Comment: Hi, I have a Oracle 11. I cant use a subquery cause this select is a subselect already

Comment: You can nest subqueries, unless you have a join condition or filter that refers to something too far up the chain. Without knowing quite what issue you're trying to solve - preferably with a reproducible example - it's difficult to suggest a suitable solution. The short answer is you can't, so you need a different approach.

Comment: Hi Alex, we can say this is my full query: `SELECT T1.CAMP_ID,
  T2.CAMP
  (SELECT OT.CAMP FROM OTHERTABLE OT WHERE OT.FK_TO_TABLE1=T1.CAMP_ID ORDER BY OT.ORDERCAMP)
FROM TABLE1 T1,
  TABLE2 T2
WHERE T1.FK_TO_T2=T2.PK;` The subquery returns more than 1 row, that is why I want to recover just first one

Comment: @AlexPoole I have edited the Question in order to add more info

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advantage". That doesn't even make _sense_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query (without the invalid `ORDER BY`) gets `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`. You can nest subqueries, but you can only refer back one level when joining; so if you did:

```
SELECT T1.CAMP_ID, T2.CAMP,
  (SELECT CAMP FROM
  FROM
    (SELECT OT.CAMP
    FROM OTHERTABLE OT
    WHERE OT.FK_TO_TABLE1=T1.CAMP_ID
    ORDER BY OT.ORDERCAMP
    )
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.FK_TO_T2=T2.PK;
```

... then you would get `ORA-00904: "T1"."CAMP_ID": invalid identifier`. Hence your question, presumably.

What you could do instead is join to the third table, and use the analytic `ROW_NUMBER()` function to assign the row number, and then use an outer select wrapped around the whole thing to only find the records with the lowest `ORDERCAMP`:

```
SELECT CAMP_ID, CAMP, OT_CAMP
FROM (
  SELECT T1.CAMP_ID, T2.CAMP, OT.CAMP AS OT_CAMP,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.CAMP_ID ORDER BY OT.ORDERCAMP) AS RN
  FROM TABLE2 T2
  JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T1.FK_TO_T2=T2.PK
  JOIN OTHERTABLE OT ON OT.FK_TO_TABLE1=T1.CAMP_ID
)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` can partition on the `T1.CAMP_ID` primary key value, or anything else that is unique.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c8d3/1), including the inner query run on its own so you can see the `RN` numbers assigned before the outer filter is applied.

Another approach is to use the aggregate [`KEEP DENSE_RANK FIRST` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm)

```
SELECT T1.CAMP_ID, T2.CAMP,
  MAX(OT.CAMP) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY OT.ORDERCAMP) AS OT_CAMP
FROM TABLE2 T2
JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T1.FK_TO_T2=T2.PK
JOIN OTHERTABLE OT ON OT.FK_TO_TABLE1=T1.CAMP_ID
GROUP BY T1.CAMP_ID, T2.CAMP;
```

Which is a bit shorter and doesn't need an inner query. I'm not sure if there's any real advantage of one over the other.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c8d3/2).

Comment: Hi @Alex Poole. I have a similar issue need help

Comment: @Aradhya - if this doesn't address your issue then you'll need to ask a new question, explaining what you've tried and what problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

In the most recent version of Oracle, you can do:

```
SELECT CAMP1, ORDERCAMP
FROM TABLENAME
ORDER BY ORDERCAMP
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Otherwise, I think you need a subquery of some sort.

Comment: @Angel . . . I think it was introduced in Oracle 12.

Answer (score -2):

You could use LIMIT or SELECT TOP 1

`SELECT CAMP1, ORDERCAMP FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY ORDERCAMP LIMIT 1`

Comment: Neither is valid syntax for Oracle. Even in 12c, which Gordon has shown.